# How to create a map on "My Maps" programmatically

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to create a map in [My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) then import a CSV file into a layer.
I was able to create the map manually from browser but I need to do this every day.

I would like to create that map programmatically every day then open it with Maps App on my phone (Nexus 4) or with browser, selecting [My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) and opening it.
Is this possible?

Is there an API that will allow me to do this?

Comment: It would be better to use Google Map API instead of my map https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=en

Comment: Really are you just saying that you would like to save a map once you've created it?